# Why is React state not working with data from external class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to Javascript and React, and as a challenge for myself im trying to build a simple calculator. My plan was to break out the calculator logic into a separate class.

I'm just testing out now, but have a very strange problem. Probably something very simple i'm not understanding.

Just trying to add numbers in my "Calculator class" right now. And get them to show in my display.

Here is my Calculator

```
class Calculator {
  constructor(prevOperand = "0", currentOperand = "0", displayValue = "0") {
    this.prevOperand = prevOperand;
    this.currentOperand = currentOperand;
    this.displayValue = displayValue;
    this.addNumber = this.addNumber;
  }

  addNumber(number) {
    if (this.currentOperand === "0") {
      this.currentOperand = number;
    } else {
      this.currentOperand += number;
    }
    // Show the number in caclulator, not working with hook
    console.log(this.currentOperand);
  }
}

export default Calculator;
```

And here is the start of my App

```
const App = (props) => {
  const calculator = new Calculator();
  const [displayValue, setDisplayValue] = useState(0);

  const onClick = (event) => {
    calculator.addNumber(event.target.textContent);
    setDisplayValue(calculator.currentOperand);
    event.stopPropagation();
  };
```

The strange thing is that my operandstring in my Calculator is only showing the last digit entered. However if i remove the call to setDisplayValue in my onClick handler, the  "Calculator" is adding the numbers as expected. In what way is my state hook affecting the result in my calculator?

Comment: Could you paste your whole code or create a sandbox for it? It would be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just found my problem.
Since my calculator where created inside my App component, I was recreating it on every re-render. So moving constructor for my class outside App solved the problem.